# laravel eloquent inserts empty record to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Am using Laravel Eloquent `create::` to insert record, but it inserts and empty record having values in only the id and timestamps.

```
$data['fname'] = $request->input('fname');
$data['lname'] = $request->input('lname');
$data['email'] = $request->input('email');
$data['phone'] = $request->input('phone');
RefUsers::create($data);
```

Then in my `RefUsers` model I have

```
protected $fillable = array('fname, lname, email,phone');
public $timestamps = false;
```

It runs without error, but it inserts empty record to db. Can anybody help?

Comment: A renowned developer should read documentation more carefully and he'd notice that his `$fillable` is defined completely wrong.

Comment: It was an oversight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fillable is an array of strings, so each field, should be on its own index like:

```
protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
```

Comment: Yours would be: protected $fillable = array('fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone');

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try correct syntax for `$fillable` array, for example:

```
protected $fillable = ['fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone'];
```

Or:

```
protected $fillable = array('fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone');
```

Second thing is you can really use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) here:

```
RefUsers::create($request->all());
```

Instead of:

```
$data['fname'] = $request->input('fname');
$data['lname'] = $request->input('lname');
$data['email'] = $request->input('email');
$data['phone'] = $request->input('phone');
RefUsers::create($data);
```